# The array doesnt print its values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make a socket io simple chat app and the connection works fine. The problems comes with the const renderChat. The console.log is read and correctly printed (with the value in the textbox) also if I put a static text it is also displayed on the frontend, however, for some reason it doesn't print

```
{msg.data["message"]}
```

which has to print each value in an array. Also I am almost certain that the array is emptied every time and the useEffect doesn't work properly but I can't really test that yet. Would be glad if I get solution to both problems!

```
import './App.css';
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";


const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001");

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [chat, setChat] = useState([]);
  const sendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("send_message", { message });
  };

  const renderChat = () => {
    return (
      chat.forEach(msg => {
        <h3>{msg.data["message"]}</h3>
        console.log(msg.data)
      })
    )
  }

    useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", message => {
      setChat([...chat, message]);
    });
  }, [socket])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input placeholder="Message..." onChange={(event) => {
        setMessage(event.target.value);}}
        />
      <button onClick={sendMessage}>Send Message</button>
      <h1>Message:</h1>
      {renderChat()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

EDIT:

Thanks to Ibrahim Abdallah, now the printing works. The only thing that doesn't work is as I feared, storing the information. Here is the piece of code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", message => {
      setChat([...chat, message]);
    });
  }, [socket])
```

For some reason when I enter for example "text1" it saves it but then if I enter "text2" it overwrites the first value "text1".
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your renderChat function to use map instead and the console log message should be before the return statement of the map function

```
const renderChat = () => {
    return (
        chat.map(msg => {
            console.log(msg.data)
            return (
                <h3>{msg.data["message"]}</h3>
            )
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please look at the post again (the EDIT version)?

Answer (score 0):

Please use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
    const renderChat = () => {
    return (
      chat.map(msg => {
        <h3>{msg.data["message"]}</h3>
        console.log(msg.data)
      })
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`

`map` actually returns an array of the returned results.

`forEach` on the other hand does not return anything.

```
const renderChat = () => {
    return (
      chat.map(msg => {
        console.log(msg.data);
        return <h3>{msg.data["message"]}</h3>;
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: I have tried this way before and it didn't work for some reason. Now I tried again and it still doesn't print anything in the frontend. The console message is executed though.

Comment: Can you provide what is printed in console.log? It may be the issue that key used is not correct.

Comment: edited my answer, you need to return the JSX, and the console.log needs to come before the return

Comment: @lanxion Now the problem is storing the values in one array. Could you please look at the edited part

Comment: this seems like a separate question, please raise it separately and just mark one of the answers as done. Avoid using this site like a thread style where you keep adding new questions with edits